# How to show the breadcrumbs in a single line in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have a code in php to show the breadcrumb it outputs like this

[the link i found the php code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/techpulsetoday/c7f8fa1a5f170f4ecbb049b63d0cd140/raw/2dd52a19e786390fd6016478ff201b5e6c4ae818/breadcrumbs-code-without-plugin.php) 
output 
`<div id="crumbs"><a href="http://localhost">Home</a> » <a href="http://localhost/about/">About The Tests</a> » <span class="current">Page Image Alignment</span></div>`

and it looks like this

```css
#crumbs a,
#crumbs span {
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    box-shadow: -3px 2px 18px -3px #000;
    background: #4489ff;
    width: max-content;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 6px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#crumbs span.current{
  background: #eef5ff !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<center>
<!-- Do Not use <center> tag ! !-->


<div id="crumbs"><a href="http://localhost">Home</a>  <a href="http://localhost/about/">About The Tests</a>  <span class="current">Page Image Alignment</span></div>


<!-- Do Not use </center> tag ! !-->
</center>
```

i want to make the breadcrumbs a single line and fancy like this .
i have made 90% percent of it but i don't know how to show the box shadow like the image down

[image]

Please tell how to. **thanks for your help** !

image desktop 
[image]

image mobile 
[image]

Comment: It's justabout styles you haven't posted here... You're looking for float, border-radius and box-shadow. That should be all.

Comment: Please tell me how to i will upvote your comment

Comment: Probably something like this `#crumbs a {border-radius-right: 50%; box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #787878; background: #0000FF; text: #fff; float: left;` and for the active page span reverse background and text color

Comment: the code still looks good but i need exactly like that an i also need it center aligned but  i upvoted your comment thanks pal

Comment: @QuestionsBoy you need to provide a minimal reproducible example by using the snippet in the editor. So that me or someone else can fix what's not working in your code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I now edited and added a code snippet please look @ozgur sar

Comment: @QuestionsBoy Please try the answer that I just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I removed the absolute positioning method, centered it and made it responsive.

```css
.crumbswrapper {text-align: center;}
#crumbs {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.innerwrap {
  display: inline-block;
  background:#4489ff;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}
.innerwrap:last-child {
  background: none;
}
.innerwrap:nth-last-child(2) {
  background: #eef5ff;
}
#crumbs a, #crumbs span {
  background:#4489ff;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 10px -4px #444;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 34px;
}
.innerwrap:nth-last-child(2) a {
  box-shadow: none!important;
}

#crumbs span.current{
  background: #eef5ff !important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #4489ff!important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="crumbswrapper">
  <div id="crumbs">
    <div class="innerwrap"><a href="http://localhost">Home</a></div>
    <div class="innerwrap"><a href="http://localhost/about/">About The Tests</a></div>
    <div class="innerwrap"><span class="current">Page Image Alignment</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks very nice ! but can you make it responsive and center algined it's good on desktop but not on mobile

Comment: Can you send screenshot of the example when it is responsive? I want to see how it collapses

Comment: @QuestionsBoy I made it responsive and centered the crumbs div